# Disable Create form on datatable with inline edit turn on

Tags: gvnix

I intended to use datatable in GvNix on an entity where the create and delete are managed by some backend logic. Only allow View and Update on the entity using inline edit datatable. I managed to use the delete=false and create=false option in the table.tagx for the particular entity. But this only disable the create and delete icon. The create form is still there. Is there a ways to disable the create form above the datatable once the datatable has been created with inline edit?

Comment: Which gvNIX are you using?

Comment: 1.5.1 RC4. I am trying Frnore's fix. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is an error on file **table.tagx** when validate *create* property.
I've fixed it with the following change:
Replace the line ~373 of file *table.tagx* from:

```
  <c:if test="${inlineCreating}">
```

to:

```
  <c:if test="${inlineCreating and create}">
```

I've applied these changes on commit: https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/commit/dd1ad58ab90998b3dcc5379fd98b8c484e61e76e

Please try it and tell me if it worked to you.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: I am using 1.5.1 RC4. Same same line is on line 364 on my version. Anyway, it worked. Thanks a lot.